# How to ensure a user is logged in before view any pages ? JSF

Tags: jsf

I have a created a project, i wish to make sure the user is logged in and authenticated with my ldap server, how would i go about this,

```
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |-- resources
 |    |-- css
 |    |    `-- style.css
 |
 |-- upload
 |    |-- uploadText.xhtml
 |
 |-- index.xhtml
 |-- SubmittedText.xhtml
 |-- etc.xhtml
```

i want to protect everything apart from the resources folder

this is my current web.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Upload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>richard.fileupload.UploadFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>sizeThreshold</param-name>
            <param-value>1024</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Upload Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/upload/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/corejsf.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>LDAP</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login-failed.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Restircted resources</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint> 
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Allowed resources</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
            <!--  <http-method>GETLIB</http-method>
            <http-method>COPY</http-method>
            <http-method>MOVE</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>PROPFIND</http-method>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>MKCOL</http-method>
            <http-method>PROPPATCH</http-method>
            <http-method>LOCK</http-method>
            <http-method>UNLOCK</http-method>
            <http-method>VERSION-CONTROL</http-method>
            <http-method>CHECKIN</http-method>
            <http-method>CHECKOUT</http-method>
            <http-method>UNCHECKOUT</http-method>
            <http-method>REPORT</http-method>
            <http-method>UPDATE</http-method>
            <http-method>CANCELUPLOAD</http-method>-->
        </web-resource-collection>
        <!-- No Auth Contraint! -->
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<security-constraint>` is missing the `<auth-constraint>`. A security constraint without an authentication constraint is basically a public resource. As an example, if you'd like to restrict all roles, then you should put the following authentication constraint within the security constraint.

```
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
```

All with all, if you want to restrict everything `/*` expect of `/javax.faces.resource/*`, then you should have the following security constraints, exactly in this order in `web.xml`:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Restircted resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint> 
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Allowed resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <!-- No Auth Contraint! -->
</security-constraint>
```

Your list of HTTP method restrictions is somewhat ridiculous, just omit it. It by default already applies on every single HTTP method.

Comment: Thank you, i have removed the HTTP method restrictions, i can not however test it now, as i can access our LDAP server off campus, but it seems to be working perfect !

Comment: I have just tested it, while it does pull up the log in page, when a user presses log in it comes up with a 403 error : `HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied`

Comment: 403 just means that the user is not allowed to view a folder. You need to let the URL point to a file. Alternatively, you need to provide a `<welcome-file>` pointing to a file in the folder which should be served when a folder is requestred. This has been explained several times in your previous questions as well. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481457/when-set-login-xhtml-as-my-homepage-it-does-not-work#comment20178619_14482254

Comment: ok thanks, i am just trying to access root, once the user is authenticated, i have not set up any folders i have just placed the web pages in root, as above shows, my `welcome-file` points to index.xhtml which is in root, the same place as the login page and the other files, or do i need to edit something else ?

Comment: The "root" `/` in URL **is** a folder :) If you didn't have the `<welcome-file>`, then you should have typed `/index.xhtml` in URL instead. So far, with the welcome file properly set, it should work fine. Does it?

Comment: Thank you, i have set the `welcome-file` to  `<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>` but i still get a 403 error after login :(

Comment: The welcome file must be a filename, not an URL. Use `<welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>`. The welcome file represents the filename of the file which the server should serve up when a folder in URL is been requested like so `/`, `/foo/`, `/bar/`, etc. Don't forget to save, rebuild, redeploy and restart after editing.

Comment: Thank you, i have changed it back to `index.xhtml` closed netbeans and chrome restarted it all but still getting the 403 :(, link to my directory http://i1081.photobucket.com/albums/j348/west-wot/DirectoryCurrent_zpsfe94e998.png

Comment: Ok, then it's likely a role problem. I wonder that as the role is restricted to `*`. What if you use `user` instead?

Comment: Ok thanks, i have changed the * to users for the role, but the same issue, this is my first time at trying anything like this

Comment: But you have specified a role of `user`. Is it now `user` or `users`? This could be as good caused by a wrong role name in `<security-role>`. Note that the login went successful (otherwise you'd have a 401).

Comment: I am sorry i don't understand, what do i need to put if i want anyone to view the pages once logged in ? i did have `<security-role>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>` and `<auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>` but it is still not working :(, the user is successfully logged in against our ldap on login however

Comment: Apparently the logged-in user does not have a role of `user`. If you are actually not using roles, then you should actually have used `<role-name>*</role-name>` inside `<security-role>` (and change that of the security auth constraint as well).

Comment: Have done that, update the original question with my current .xml but still getting the 403 :(

Comment: What if you open the restriced page directly instead of a folder? E.g. `http://localhost:8080/context/index.xhtml` instead of `http://localhost:8080/context/`.

Comment: then i get the login page, once logged in i get the 403, if i directly open the page i still get the 403

Comment: Well, you're successfully logged-in, but the role is not right. Sorry, LDAP is beyond me. The web part is fine. Your best bet is to ask the LDAP admin for the right role name so that you can specify exactly this role name in `<role-name>`.

Comment: is there a way not to have any roles ? as they are not needed for this project ?

Comment: Just spoken to them and there are no roles in the LDAP directory

Comment: i also get this error now in glassfish `WARNING: No Principals mapped to Role [*].`

Comment: Oh that's actually helpful. Have you enabled principal to role mapping in Glassfish realm config? See also this related Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728164/glassfish-3-1-default-principal-to-role-mapping

Comment: i will look now, i don't think i have enabled that as i am not sure what it is or does

Comment: From the linked question: *"Then on the glassfish console I need to tick the options in: Configuration -> server-config -> security -> Default Principal To Role Mapping"*

Comment: Thanks i have doen that, no longer getting that error now in glassfish but still getting a 403 error :(

Comment: also get this error in the console `WARNING: Cannot create update center Image for C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2; Update Center functionality will not be available in Admin Console`

Comment: The issue was no roles was declared in glassfish server, so just added a role and things seem to be ok now !